# How to add a class in li-Tag of a menu?

Tags: class, menu, impresspages

I seem to be blind, stupid or both but I can't add own classes to li-items of a menu. Here are multiple tries:

```
<?php
  $options = array(
    'items' => 'menu1', //menu to be displayed
    'class' => 'own-class-test-1',
    'css' => array(
      'class' => 'own-class-test-2',
    ),
    'active' => 'own-active-test-2',
    'attributes' => array(
      'id' => 'ipsTest',
      'class' => 'nav nav-pills pull-right'
    )
  );
  echo ipSlot('menu', $options); ?>
```

Can anybody help me with this? I am only able to change the preset like active-class. Adding classes to the ul works without problems.

Thank you & cheers, 
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I've check the code. Currently you can modify `<li>` only through variable defined here - https://www.impresspages.org/docs/navigation

There's no "default" things to add extra class for all `<li>`. However, if it selects every tag then what's the point adding it? Add required styles directly through CSS.